# Как предотвратить закрытие программы по выполнению ?

Tags: golang

Взялся за изучение Go.

Написал простейшую программу:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
   fmt.Print("Enter a ft: ")
   var ft float64
   fmt.Scanf("%f", &ft)

   output := ft * 0.3048

   fmt.Println(output, "m")
}
```

После скомпилировав выполнил её, после выполнения она моментально закрывается.

Вопрос как избежать моментального закрытия ? (желательно ссылку на эту тему в документации)

Comment: запустить сначала cmd/terminal, а уже в ней/нем запускать программу

Comment: @Etki то есть скомпилированный exe'шник будет работать только из консоли ?

Comment: Работать он будет откуда угодно, он же exe'шником быть не перестает. А то, что вы описываете особенность видового поведения.

Comment: @Bastian, скомпилированный экзешник будет работать где угодно, но после того, как он отработает, открытое специально под него окно терминала/cmd исчезнет, как вы видели.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main(){
         fmt.Scanf(" ")
}
```

Но вообще так не делают, а просто выполняют команду из терминала.

Comment: С пустым параметром `Scanf()` не ждёт ввод. Если добавить *любой* символ, то на моей машине начинает ждать, например, `fmt.Scanf("\n")`. Можно использовать `bufio`, `io/ioutil`, чтобы прочитать строку со стандартного ввода.

+1 за "просто выполняют команду из терминала."

Comment: Поправил, мой косяк.
Строка формата должна быть хоть какой.

Comment: А на счет bufio и др., смысл импортировать кучу модлей даже стандартных, fmt уже у него импортирован, так почему бы Scanf и не воспользоваться.

Answer (score 1):

Пример кода, остановка программы после написания "q" в терминале.

```
fmt.Println("Press 'q' to quit")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        exit := scanner.Text()
        if exit == "q" {
            break
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Press 'q' to quit")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ответы должны содержать не только код, но и пояснения.